# Deploying JavaFX Application with Intellij

Tags: java, maven, javafx, deployment

I created quite complex project with JavaFX and now I'm having some trouble deploying it, as I never deployed any app in Java before.
I tried using Intellij "Build artificial" but I always get "Error: corrupted jarfile" when I try to open the the Jar it builds.

Any suggestions? I'm using external libraries from Maven and some local ones too if it helps...

**Edit:
Ok I changed some of the settings in the Make Artificial, now I don't get that error.
I get this Exception, seems it can't file the fxml file...**

```
        Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
            at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
            at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
            at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
            at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
            at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
            at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
            at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
            at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
            at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
            at sample.Main.start(Main.java:20)
            at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
            at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
            at

 javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

***SOLVED!: just played with the fxml files patches and it fixed it...***